# Como inserir esse texto no PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, delphi, postgresql, sql-update, richtextbox

Estou usando uma query Delphi e preciso inserir o texto abaixo num campo tipo text

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Calibri;}{\f1\froman\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\fi-11\qj\tx142\tx360\tx720\tx9700\cf1\lang1046\f0\fs18 ssssssss\par
\par
Cabe ao empregador quanto ao EPI, orientar e treinar o trabalhador sobre o uso adequado, guarda e conserva\'e7\'e3o.\par
\pard\fi-11\tx142\tx360\tx720\tx9700\par
\cf0\f1\fs24 CONTE\'daDO PROGRAM\'c1TICO\par
\cf1\b\i\f0\fs18\par
\b0\i0 - Utiliza\'e7\'e3o adequada\par
- Respons\'e1bilidade sobre Guarda e Conserva\'e7\'e3o\par
- Cumprir determina\'e7\'f5es do empregador sobre uso adequado \par
- Comunicar ao empregador qualquer altera\'e7\'e3o que torne impr\'f3prio para o uso \par
- C.A Certificado de aprova\'e7\'e3o  \par
\par
\par
Com Certificado para a Empresa e Lista de Presen\'e7a.\par
\par
\pard\sb100\sa100\qj\cf0\f1\fs24 c\\sdc\par
\par
\pard\sb100\sa100\par
\pard\fi-11\tx142\tx360\tx720\tx9700\cf1\f0\fs18\par
\pard\cf0\f2\fs16\par
}
```

Esse texto vem de um arquivo RTF, então ele tem essa formatação doida, ja tentei com LoadFromFile, mas quando grava ele aparece um monte de ???? ao inves do texto

O comando usado é:

```
...
Arquivo := Stream.LoadFromFile('arquivo.rtf');
S := Arquivo.DataString;

Query := TQuery.Create(nil);
... 
Query.SQL.Add('update tabela set campotext = '+QuotedStr(S)+'');
Query.ExecSQL;
```

O erro:

```
SQL Error: ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 \\fnilTahoma;}}

\viewkind4\uc1\pard\qj\lang1046\f0\fs16\\zdv\\cxcv\par

\pard\par

}

"
LINE 2: texto = '{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\...
                           ^
```

Ja tentei colocar uns escapes mas sem chance

Comment: você tem que usar parâmetros na query, ou dar um replace em cada `'` para `'''` (o replace é gambiarra)

Comment: veja: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries e http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Supplying_Parameters_at_Runtime

Answer (score 1):

Parte dessa questão já lhe respondi aqui [RitchEdit Delphi bagunça texto ao gravar no banco PostgreSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/310219/ritchedit-delphi-bagun%C3%A7a-texto-ao-gravar-no-banco-postgresql/310981#310981)

Sobre gravar blobs utilizando instruções SQL faça assim:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  q: TFDQuery;
  s: TMemoryStream;
begin
  s := TMemoryStream.Create;
  RichEdit1.Lines.SaveToStream(s);

  s.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

  q := TFDQuery.Create(Self);
  q.Connection := FDConnection1;
  q.SQL.Text := 'update tabela set campobytea = :b where (id = 1)';
  q.ParamByName('b').LoadFromStream(s, ftBlob);
  q.ExecSQL;
end;
```

*Este código é apenas para exemplificar. Considere o uso de TRY EXCEPT e TRY FINALY no código de produção.*